# Could not download CSV file on browser using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, csv

I need to download the mysql record to csv file on browser but as per my code it's not working as expected. Here is my code:

```
$scope.downloadAllCustomerData=function(){
        var url2='../service/admin/customer/customer.php?action=downloadAllCustomerData';
        var method='GET';
        var data1='';
        DataService.connectToServerSideScript(method,url2,data1)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('response',response);

        },function(error) {

        })
    }
```

Here is my client side code which making request to sevre to download the `.CSV` file.

```
if ($_REQUEST["action"]=="downloadAllCustomerData") {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');  
        $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
        fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'Name', 'Email', 'MObile No'));  
        $sql = "SELECT user_id,name,email,mobile from cb_customer_info ORDER BY user_id DESC";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $number_of_rows= count($row);
            if ($number_of_rows > 0) {
                fputcsv($output, $row);
                $data=array("status"=>1,"msg"=>"Downloaded all data successfully.");
            }else{
                $data=array("status"=>0,"msg"=>"No record found.");
            }
            fclose($output);
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Here I am trying to download the mysql record into .csv file. I need when user will click on the button those record will be downloaded on the browser.

Comment: A quick reminder that you are not "explaining" your code. I appreciate English is not your first language, but there is an expectation here that when people offer help with you wording, you pay attention and change course. There is no reason that you should still be using this awkward phrasing now, since you know full well there is a better phrase. "Here is my code" is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Better to form data and echo/print to browser instead of using php://output stream.

Usual headers for Download,

```
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
            header('Content-Type: '.$content_type); 
            header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
            header("Pragma: private"); 
            header("Expires: -1"); 
            header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
            header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);
```

Comment: I used all header but still same issue.

Comment: Can you try directly dumping data on echo/print.

Comment: I did like `echo ($output);` but its not downloading.

Comment: I am pasting sample code below,

            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
            header('Content-Type: '.$content_type); 
            header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
            header("Pragma: private"); 
            header("Expires: -1"); 
            header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
            header("Content-Length: ".$filesize); 
   
                            print $data; 
                            ob_flush(); 
                            flush();

Comment: I did as per you but its writing all data in browser console but not downloading any csv file.